# Min and Max values of Float and Double types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, floating-point, double, primitive-types

It's simple to find out what the exact `min` and `max` values for `Int` and `Long` integers are in Kotlin:

**Signed 32 bit Integer**:

```
Int.MIN_VALUE       // -2147483648
Int.MAX_VALUE       //  2147483647
```

**Signed 64 bit Integer**:

```
Long.MIN_VALUE      // -9223372036854775808
Long.MAX_VALUE      //  9223372036854775807
```

However, if I try to print `Float` or `Double` types' ranges of `min` and `max` values, I'll get unbalanced numbers (where both values will be expressed using a scientific notation).

**Signed 32 bit Floating Point Number**:

```
Float.MIN_VALUE     //  1.4e-45
Float.MAX_VALUE     //  3.4028235e38
```

**Signed 64 bit Floating Point Number**:

```
Double.MIN_VALUE    //  4.9e-324
Double.MAX_VALUE    //  1.7976931348623157e308
```

Why the positive and negative values of `Float` and `Double` types are so "***unbalanced***"?

P. S.

In C# language, `min` and `max` **absolute** values of Double are identical (or "balanced").

```
public const double MaxValue = 1.7976931348623157E+308;
```

---

```
public const double MinValue = -1.7976931348623157E+308;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The conceptual definition of `MIN_VALUE` is different for integers vs floating-point numbers.

- `Int.MIN_VALUE` is the largest negative value.
- `Float.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest positive value.

In other words, `1.4E-45` is `0.00[40 zeroes]0014`, and *not* a very large negative number. The largest possible negative value is represented by `-1 * Float.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: The largest positive float value and the largest negative float value are identical (except for the sign bit). `Float.MIN_VALUE` and `Float.MAX_VALUE` are so different because they are the number closest to 0 and the number furthest from 0 possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this discussion because I made the mistake of expecting that `Float.MIN_VALUE` and `Double.MIN_VALUE` correlated with the `Int.MIN_VALUE`, in that they both should represent the most negative value for that datatype.

For a `Float` or `Double` you have the additional properties, aside from `MIN_VALUE` or `MAX_VALUE`, of `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and `POSITIVE_INFINITY` which technically could be your largest negative and positive value.  I was trying to find a number that would represent a value of a var that had not been used yet.  `MIN_VALUE` didn't work for me because I was dealing with positive and negative numbers.