# subtracting Float.MIN_VALUE from another float number has no effect in android application

Tags: java, android, kotlin, floating-point, precision

I am working on an android application where for a part of the app, I have 2 floating point values and I cannot have them be exactly the same because this is causing a bug in one of my screens. Those numbers are being sent from a server and are out of my control (e.g. I cannot force them to be different).

The app is written in Kotlin, but I assume that this issue is similar (if not exactly the same) for Java, as Kotlin uses the JVM behind the scenes.

I thought of a "creative" way of solving this without changing my logic too much, by subtracting `Float.MIN_VALUE` from one of them, making them **almost, but not exactly** the same. What I actually need to happen is for `if(a == b)` to fail (where `b` is actually `a - Float.MIN_VALUE`).

But to my surprise, when the code runs, `if(a == b)` returns `true`. When I opened the "evaluate" window in Android Studio here is what I found out:

[image]

Let me reiterate that `currentPayment` is a `Float`, so there shouldn't be any auto-conversions or rounding going on (like when dividing `Float` by an `Int` for example).

Let me also point out that I can guarantee that `currentPayment` is not
`Float.MAX_VALUE` or `-Float.MAX_VALUE` (so the result of the operation is within the bounds of `Float`).

According to docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316499/min-and-max-values-of-float-and-double-types-in-kotlin#answer-56316624) `Float.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest positive non-zero value of `Float` and has a value of `1.4E-45`, which is confirmed here:

[image]

I also saw in another post (which I cannot find again for some reason), that this can also be thought of as the maximum precision of `Float`, which makes sense.

Since `currentPayment` is a `Float`, I would expect it should be able to hold **any** floating point value within the bounds of `Float` to it's maximum precision (i.e. `Float.MIN_VALUE`).
Therefore I would expect `currentPayment` to **NOT** equal `currentPayment - Float.MIN_VALUE`, but alas that is not the case.

Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: see `Math.nextDown()` (or similar) - float (or double) have a *precision* (see `Math.ulp()`) - MIN_VALUE is probably too small for the used numbers (e.g. for `1.0f` the *ulp* is about `1.19E-7` while MIN_VALUE is `1.4E-45`)

Comment: @user16320675 I'm afraid I dont really understand what you mean by your first comment. would you please elaborate in more detail?
Also, I dont understand why my assumption is wrong. while there are definitely A LOT of options, it is a finite number. If I can have a float that represents 0.000.....00145 (Float.MIN_VALUE), why cant i have a float that represents 1.0000.......0000145?

Comment: @user16320675 if i do `1f.nextDown` i get `0.99999994`. why is that? why is it only 8 decimal points? how can i get 10 decimal points? or 20?

Comment: @user16320675 so if i can only represent floating numbers that have 10 characters, including the "." (because `1f.nextDown` has 10 characters), how is it possible that Float.MIN_VALUE exists and i can assign it to a variable? is has much more than 10 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since `currentPayment` is a `Float`, I would expect it should be able to hold **any** floating point value within the bounds of `Float` to it's maximum precision (i.e. `Float.MIN_VALUE`).

This is a wrong assumption. Float is called "float" because it has floating precision. The amount of precision depends on how big the number is that you're storing. The smallest possible float value is smaller than the precision of almost any other possible number, so it is too small to affect them if you add or subtract it. At the high end, Float numbers have precisions that are much greater than the integer 1. If you subtract 999,000,000 from `Float.MAX_VALUE`, it will still return `Float.MAX_VALUE` because the precision is so poor at the highest end.

Also, since floating point numbers are not stored in base-10, they are inappropriate for storing currency amounts, because you can never exactly represent a decimal fraction. (I mention that because your variable name has the word "payment" in it, which is a red flag.)

You should either use BigDecimal, Long, or Int to represent currency, so your currency amounts and arithmetic will be exact.

---

Edit:
Here's an analogy to help understand it, since it is hard to contemplate binary numbers. Floats are 32-bits in Java and Kotlin, but imagine we have a special kind of computer that can store a floating point number in base-10. Each bit on this computer is not just 0 or 1, but can be anything from 0 to 9. A Float on this computer can have 4 digits and a decimal place, but the decimal place is floating, so it can be placed anywhere relative to the four digits. So a Float on this computer is always five bits--four of the bits are the digits, and the fifth bit tells you where the decimal place goes.

In this imaginary computer's Float, the smallest possible number that can be represented is `.0001` and the largest possible number is `9999.`. You can't represent `9999.5` or even `1000.5` because there aren't enough digits available. There's no fixed amount of precision--the precision is determined by where the decimal place is in the current number. Precision is better for numbers with a decimal place farther to the left.

For the number storage format to be able to have a *fixed* precision, we would have to fix the decimal point in one place for all numbers. We would have to choose a precision. Suppose we chose a precision of `0.001`. Our fifth bit that told us where the decimal place goes in the floating point can now just be used for a fifth digit. Now we know the precision is **always** `0.001`, but the largest possible number we can represent is `99.999` and the smallest possible number is `0.001`, a much smaller possible range than with floating point. This limitation is the reason floating points are used instead.

Comment: so Float.MIN_VALUE is not the precision of float? so i dont really understand what the precision is... are you saying that even though 1.0 is a float, it uses a different amount of memory than, lets say 1.0000000.....123, and therefore there IS some sort of auto-adjustment behind the scenes, which seems to be to the LEAST amount of accuracy? am I not able to hold a variable with the value of 1.000...000123? clearly I can because Float.MIN_VALUE exists and I can store it in a variable, so how can i get (and store) Float.MIN_VALUE + 1?

Comment: Floats always are 32 bits, but the precision is floating so a big range of numbers is possible to represent. There is no fixed precision like with Ints, where the numbers are equally spaced values of 1 apart. This is why `Float.MAX_VALUE` is many quadrillions of times bigger than `Int.MAX_VALUE`, but it can represent numbers that are many quadrillions times smaller than the integer 1, even though `Int` also is stored in 32 bits. I added another explanation to my answer that might help you understand.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. so... a few example to make sure i got it right: i can try to calculate `9999. - .0001`. mathematically the answer is `9998.9999`, but the computer can only hold 5 digits, so the output would be either `9998.` (cutting off the end) or `9999.` (rounding)? i could accurately calculate `1.000 - .0001` and get `.9999`, but CANNOT accurately calculate `1.000 + .0001 `, which would result in `1.000`? if i were to try to count sequentially on this computer with `0.1` increments, it would be `999.8`, `999.9`, `1000.`, `1000.`, `1000.`...?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: so other types of number data holder (e.g. `Double`) have some internal mechanism that makes them safe for arithmetic operations? (p.s. i accepted your answer)

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by safe. Double has the same issues as Float that I described above, but it can handle much smaller or bigger numbers because it uses 64 bits instead of 32. Int and Long are exact integer precision so they give you exact values when adding, subtracting, and multiplying, but this means remainders are lost when you divide them. BigDecimal is the only one that is lossless for any arithmetic.

Comment: "safe" meaning i can do mathematic operations without worrying about this kind of thing. about Double i got confused... i meant BigDecimal which you mentioned